# dbWriteTable function from R odbc package not working Error indecipherable

Tags: r, odbc

I am using the dbWriteTable function of the odbc package to write to a MSSQL database. Everything goes smoothly except for one data.frame, playerGame

The code below indicates an error but it is not very descriptive

It is the largest data.frame being transferred and I am just wondering if this could be an issue

Over 300,000 rows, 43 columns. The equivalent rds file is 11MB

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
               DSN = "premier")

 dbWriteTable(con, "playerGame", playerGame)
Error: <SQL> 'CREATE TABLE "playerGame" (
"LASTNAME" varchar(255),
...
"off" varchar(255)
)
'
 nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S21: [Microsoft][SQL Ser
```

Comment: Is the error cut off like that? If so, try running in different modes (Rscript, Rgui, Rterm) to get full message.

Comment: You could try writing smaller samples of that df and see if it is the size or not. Though I would not guess it is.

Comment: @Parfait Tried in script and RStudio console. Not sure how to do others. Did get slight lengthening [SQL Server Na      which is probably start of Native

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Just a 6 row sample did not work. I'll have a look at restricting columns

Comment: It looks like there may be a column limitation. I split the original file into two with 22 and 21 columns respectively 300,000+ rows and dbWriteTable worked successfully

Comment: However, when i try to replicate a toy example with 43 columns and 2 rows there is no issue writing it so ...?

Comment: It may be a data limit issue, no specific row or column number but a combination with data bytes. Does your data carry many, potentially long string columns? What happens if you re-run whole dataframe through `dbWriteTable` now that the table is created with `overwrite=FALSE`?

Comment: I knew something wasn't right! `dbWriteTable` is not a method of [RODBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) but DBI. What happens when you use RODBC's `sqlSave`? In fact, please edit post and show all `library` lines, even odbc object assignment.

Comment: @Parfait. Doing the RODBC sqlSave route did work as it showed error. I had 2 columns 'off' and 'OFF'. This had not caused a problem in R or saving to files but did when getting a database involved. Thanks very much